# Best Practices for adding Exchange Archive to current 3 server setup

Tags: exchange-2010, vmware-vsphere, archive

I'm looking to add an Archive Database (which I know is just a Mailbox Database) to our current Exchange 2010 environment.  I have done this in the past at a previous job, but we had a simpler setup than at this current job.  I've been trying to find some best practices to make sure it's setup in an ideal way, but so far not finding the details I would prefer.  Hoping someone on here can give me a few pointers.

Currently we have a 3 server setup, Server1, Server2 and Server3.  Three databases of course, DB1, DB2 and DB3.  We have a DAG setup between them.

Server1 has DB1 and DB3 on it, DB1 is not active, DB3 is active.

Server2 has DB1 and DB2 on it, both are active.

Server3 has DB2 and DB3 on it, both are not active.

All three servers are virtual (VMware).  Each one is setup identical to the other as follows:

```
C:\ 60GB - OS
E:\ 600GB - DB (currently only 90GB used, pointing to Datastore just for Server2)
F:\ 200GB - Log (2GB used, pointing to same Datastore as above)
G:\ 200GB - Restore (0 used, pointing to same Datastore as above)
```

The drives are all set to Thin Provisioning, and it looks as though I have 600GB of available space.  They have not been on Exchange that long and only have about 70GB worth of PSTs to import back in that will be going to the Archive Database, plus anything older than 2 years from their current inbox that will be moved into there.

I was considering placing the Archive DB on the E:\ drive of Server3 (only) like the current DB, but wasn't sure if that was acceptable.  I don't plan on setting the Archive DB up with the DAG, just plan on having it as a single repository for older emails and manually back it up every now and then.

If anyone has any suggestions on this I would appreciate it the input.  I've done it on a slightly smaller scale before and it worked well, but like to think it through before pulling the trigger, especially at a new job. :)  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

No problem adding a database to the DAG but only having one copy.

It'll squawk during a switchover about not being to activate the database on the server that does not have  copy.

If you have the disk space though, you might as well enable replication of it, there really isn't much of a 'cost' other than the disk space.  Theoretically as you move content out of the 'live' dbs into the archive DB, you might be able to reclaim some space eventually.